# In Westworld, why wouldn't they use an EMP (Electro Magnetic Pulse) device to knock out all the hosts in the park?

Tags: westworld-2016, westworld

As per the title, why wouldn't there be any safety measures in place, such as an EMP (Electromagnetic Pulse) device, to knock out the hosts in case of an emergency?

Comment: How would they do that?  Detonate a nuclear bomb near the park?

Comment: @Buzz - Build a [bigger version of this](https://hackaday.com/2016/10/12/become-very-unpopular-very-fast-with-this-diy-emp-generator/)?

Comment: https://www.evaluationengineering.com/emp-measurements-nonnuclear-electromagnetic-pulse-generation

Comment: @Buzz Im sure that an EMP device could be built without the need of a nuclear detonation, as state by JohnP above.

Comment: How is this off topic? I asked a question relating to a popular SciFi series.

Comment: Wouldn’t that knock out the doors, vehicles, systems, too? And presumably everything (including hosts) resets rather than dies, so it becomes a question of whether you can reset the equipment and clean up all the hosts in time (or between large EMPs). Assuming the hosts are indeed vulnerable to EMPs.

Comment: It isn't off topic, at least not for the reason given.

Comment: @Pam indeed it would knock out the hosts and all electronic equipment in Westworld, however, I don't think it would just reset, but perhaps knock them out long enough to be collected and sorted. Anyway, was just a thought, all comments/thoughts welcome. Shame they shut this down though, I still cannot see how it is "off topic" :confused.

Comment: @MickIlovski I tried to edit it to ask if there’s anything in the series (or film? In universe at any rate) that would imply some sort of universal reset signal for the hosts. I guess it didn’t pass peer review. I don’t think it’s off topic since it clearly relates directly to West World, even though you are asking about EMP (which isn’t SciFi!). It’s not clear how much "meat" is in the hosts and if an EMP would actually shut them down (assuming one like the one in Oceans 11 could be fabricated).

Comment: @Pam thank you for trying and for your responses :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring the question of whether Delos has the capacity to fire the sort of nuclear weapon or weapon-scale EMP that would be required for a park of that size (they don't), ignoring the damage that would be done to the assets in their other parks (considerable) and ignoring the potential side-effects on whatever's outside their parks (catastrophic), I suspect the simplest answer is that the hosts are likely to be relatively unaffected by an EMP.

[The human body forms a pretty effective Faraday cage for enclosed electronics](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a242990.pdf) and the pulse strength would need to destroy embedded electronics has to be very considerable, well beyond what you could get from a typical [airbursted nuclear weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_electromagnetic_pulse#Soviet_Test_184).

As we can see from the image below, their bodies are largely *fake-organic* material controlled by a computer core housed inside the brain-pan, surrounded by fake skull tissue, a fake brain and a secondary inner skull filled with fluid. Assuming the host tissue is roughly analogous to organic tissue, an EMP would be relatively ineffective at shutting down the electronic components unless it was very close indeed or ridiculously powerful.

Warning. NSFW - Icky.

> [image]

Comment: Although one could assume that in such a technologically advanced realm, such as in Westworld, that an EMP device of such magnitude could also exist. This is a plausible and well researched answer based on our current realm.

Comment: @MasterMick - Sure, but if we're going to invent magical weapons, we could just as easily say "maybe it's because host material has a special resistance to EMP" :-)

Comment: This answer is no longer valid as of Season 3. :)

Comment: @Pastafarian - I'm not up to date on the show. You're welcome to post a conflicting answer if there's new canon